# WebGL support on VirtualBox guest

Tags: debian, virtualbox

I've managed to install a Debian 7.3 as guest on virtualbox 4.3.6 VM with guest additions, and I'm not able to make work webGL.

While I'm able to see openGL working (tried with `glxinfo` and `glxgears` from the command line), I'm not able to make work webGL on Firefox/Chrome/Iceweasel (didn't try other browsers). For checking if webgl is ok I'm used to surf to http://get.webgl.org/; a couple of notes stating the point at which I'm arrived:

- setting webgl.force-enabled to true in the `about:config` firefox page (and later all fore-related stuff to true);
- checked up that the guest additions installation process went allright (I had to install the right kernel headers module);
- enabled 3D acceleration for that VM;
- in the host machine (Ubuntu 12.04) webGL works well.

So, at this point: is it possible to make webGL work in a debian guest OS (or generally in a guest OS, because maybe this isn't supported)? I think that more simple the solution, less custom it is and so less subject to weird errors.

Here follows a couple of links at which I'm arrived to:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webgl-dev-list/VBmcmEMXAL0;
- http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/uC2UCk1UQ9htmqyPXtt0.

## Update 1

Tried also with Ubuntu 13.10 guest, same result.

## Update 2

Result of `glxinfo`:

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: Chromium
server glx version string: 1.3 Chromium
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address
client glx vendor string: Chromium
client glx version string: 1.3 Chromium
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address
GLX version: 1.3
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address
OpenGL vendor string: Humper
OpenGL renderer string: Chromium
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Chromium 1.9
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, GL_ARB_depth_texture, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture, 
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query, GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite, 
    GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, GL_ARB_texture_compression, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_env_add, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, 
    GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_window_pos, 
    GL_EXT_blend_color, GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, GL_EXT_fog_coord, 
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_secondary_color, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, 
    GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, 
    GL_EXT_texture_object, GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, 
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, 
    GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_NV_vertex_program, 
    GL_NV_vertex_program1_1, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_100, GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, 
    GL_CR_state_parameter, GL_CR_cursor_position, GL_CR_bounding_box, 
    GL_CR_print_string, GL_CR_tilesort_info, GL_CR_synchronization, 
    GL_CR_head_spu_name, GL_CR_performance_info, GL_CR_window_size, 
    GL_CR_tile_info, GL_CR_saveframe, GL_CR_readback_barrier_size, 
    GL_CR_server_id_sharing, GL_CR_server_matrix,  GL_EXT_stencil_two_side

96 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x021 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0d7 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0d8 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0d9 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0da 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0db 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0dc 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0dd 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0de 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0df 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0e0 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0e1 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0e2 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0e3 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0e4 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0e5 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0e6 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0e7 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0e8 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0e9 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0ea 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0eb 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0ec 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0ed 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0ee 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0ef 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0f0 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0f1 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0f2 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0f3 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0f4 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0f5 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0f6 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0f7 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0f8 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0f9 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0fa 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0fb 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0fc 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0fd 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0fe 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0ff 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x100 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x101 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x102 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x103 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x104 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x105 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x106 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x107 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x108 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x109 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x10a 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x10b 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x10c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x10d 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x10e 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x10f 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x110 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x111 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x112 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x113 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x114 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x115 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x116 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x117 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x118 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x119 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x11a 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x11b 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x11c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x11d 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x11e 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x11f 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x120 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x121 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x122 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x123 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x124 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x125 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x126 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x127 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x128 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x129 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x12a 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x12b 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x12c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x12d 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x12e 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x12f 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x130 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x131 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x132 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x133 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x134 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x046 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y y   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None

96 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x021 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0d7 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0d8 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0d9 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0da 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0db 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0dc 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0dd 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0de 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0df 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0e0 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0e1 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0e2 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0e3 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0e4 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0e5 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0e6 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0e7 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0e8 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0e9 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0ea 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0eb 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0ec 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0ed 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0ee 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0ef 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0f0 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0f1 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0f2 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0f3 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0f4 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0f5 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0f6 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0f7 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0f8 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0f9 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0fa 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0fb 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0fc 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0fd 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0fe 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x0ff 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x100 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x101 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x102 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x103 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x104 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x105 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x106 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x107 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x108 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x109 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x10a 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x10b 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x10c 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x10d 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x10e 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x10f 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x110 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x111 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x112 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x113 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x114 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x115 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x116 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x117 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x118 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x119 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x11a 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x11b 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x11c 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x11d 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x11e 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x11f 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x120 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x121 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x122 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x123 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x124 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x125 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x126 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x127 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x128 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x129 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x12a 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x12b 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x12c 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x12d 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x12e 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x12f 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x130 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x131 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x132 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x133 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x134 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
0x046 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  1 1 None
```

Comment: what does glxinfo say? WebGL requires a certain level of OpenGL support. At least OpenGL 2.0 (or maybe 2.1).

Comment: I am also running into this problem. glxinfo shows that it has OpenGL 2.1.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have the exact setup you are using, I was able to run WebGL under firefox with the host running Fedora 21, virtualbox version 4.3.32, and Fedora 22 as the guest. I also tried Centos 7 as the guest, with success. So it is possible to run WebGL in a guest using VirtualBox. I also tried Fedora 20 as the guest with success. You may want to visit the site www.doesmybrowsersupportwebgl.com and see what it tells you.

Comment: Oh thank you, but sadly in the meanwhile that project has been closed and I don't have anymore that VM or that setup. I wouldn't even be able to make further tests nor accept any answer.